# Updating entities in Entity Framework results in new rows being created

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a situation where I have a table of users and a table of locations. There is a many to many relationship between the two so they are joined via a link table that just consists of two columns; UserID and LocationID. These are FK's to the ID columns on the User and Location tables respectively.

I want to be able to update current users to link them to current locations and visa versa. The users already exist and the locations already exist in the DB but there is currently no link between the two.

When I update the User object, even though I have set the UserLocations property to the list of Locations I want to link together (along with the ID being populated correctly) and just before the update happens everything looks good, on inserting to the DB a brand new Location is created in the Location table for each entry in the list. This results in what is essentially duplicate rows just with different PK's. I haven't got to it yet but I'm assuming that as soon as I try to implement the same functionality on Locations, it will duplicate Users.

For example, for a user with ID 1 and a list of locations with IDs 1, 2 and 3. I'd expect the rows in the link table to read 1|1, 1|2 and 1|3. However, it is creating three new locations with IDs 4, 5 and 6 but the rest of the data being identical to that of IDs 1, 2 and 3 and inserting 1|4, 1|5 and 1|6 in to the link table.

If I have supplied Entity Framework with a list of objects that already have IDs populated, I'd expect it to recognise there is already an existing row in the database and just use that ID to do the insert in to the UserLocation link table.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: do you fetch the location from the database and add the fetched location to the user? or do you simply add a new location to the user?

Comment: could you please share the code

Comment: @Pali Yeah, I am fetching the location from the database first and setting the list of locations that I receive from the DB to the property of UserLocations on the User object. There are no new location objects being made.